# Which 18650 battery connection layout is best?

Tags: batteries, configuration

I am building a 5S6P battery with 18650 cells.
I have limited space so the geometrical layout is constrained.

I can think of 2 "optimal" ways to layout the cells connections but I don't know which is best.

[image: Battery connections]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utro9.png)

(the drawing only shows the top view of the pack. Left and right are two different connection configurations)

The left layout has more parallel connections, while the right one has more series connections.

Which should be favored and why? (svg file of the drawing can be D/L here https://easyupload.io/1b2eup)

Comment: Sure you don't mean 5S6P?

Comment: You are right. 5 in series, 6 in parallel

Comment: Well I'm not a battery expert. But both show six cells in parallel, in five series groups. The only difference between the two are the number of series inter-connections. Given that such a pack could deliver hundreds of Amperes, I'd pick the one with duplicated series connections (labeled parallel above), as resistive losses will be less. Note two more connections (the middle two) can also be made on left example. Perhaps it may be easier to understand if purple were replaced with red and blue, for top and bottom of cell.